# How to iterate over list of dictionary in python?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, python-2.7

I have a `list of dictionary` in python i.e.

```
listofobs = [{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 6, 12, 39, 52), 'ip': u'1.4.128.0', 'user': u'lovestone'}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 6, 12, 40, 32), 'ip': u'192.168.21.45', 'user': u'b'}]
```

I want to use all of the keys and value of `listofobs` variable in a Django-template. For example:

For the first iteration:

```
timestamp = 7 july 2012, 12:39 Am
ip = 1.4.128.0
user = lovestone
```

and for the second iteration :

```
 timestamp = 7 july 2012, 12:40 Am
 ip =  192.168.21.45
 user = b
```

and so on ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for a in listofobs:
    print str( a['timestamp'] ), a['ip'], a['user']
```

Will iterate over the list of dict's, then to use them in the template just wrap it in the needed django syntax and which is quite similar to regular python.

Answer (score 3):

Django template syntax lets you loop over a list of dicts:

```
{% for obj in listofobjs %}
    timestamp = {{ obj.timestamp }}
    ip = {{ obj.ip }}
    user = {{ obj.user }}
{% endfor %}
```

All you need to is make sure listofobjs is in your context for rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the examples for the [built in `for` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

Looping over items (your outer loop):

```
{% for obj in listofobjs %}
    {# do something with obj (just print it for now) #}
    {{ obj }}
{% endfor %}
```

And then loop over the items in your dictionary object:

```
{% for key, value in obj.items %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```